# Can't Understand Code fragment

Tags: c

I cannot understand how the code is giving output of the prime factors of input..and what is the use of temp variable in this code?another question is what is the purpose of i=1 in the code fragment?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int number,i,temp;
    scanf("%d",&number);

    if(number<0)
    {
      printf("%d = -1 x ",number); //just printing
      number=number*-1; //multiplication by -1
    }
    else
    {
      printf("%d = ",number); //just printing
    }
    for(i=2;i*i<=number;i++)
    {
      if(number%i==0)
      {
         printf("%d x ",i);
         number=number/i;
         temp=i;
         i=1;
      }
    }
    printf("%d\n",number);

    return 0;
}


sample input:100
sample output:100 = 2 x 2 x 5 x 5
sample input:20
sample output:20 = 2 x 2 x 5
```

Comment: No use of `temp` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously mentioned, temp is unused.

The way this prints the prime numbers is by trying over and over to divide the number by the smallest number possible. That is the purpose of i=1.

So take 175.

First, the loop is initialized at 2. It then increments i until 175 % i == 0. When this happens, it means that i is a factor of 175. So it prints i and divides 175 by i. This ensures you won't double-count the factor. Here, this will happen first for i == 5. So now, num = 175/5 = 35.

At this point, i is reset to 1. The first thing that happens at the end of the loop block is that i is incremented to 2. So now again, it looks for the smallest factor. Again, it finds 5.

If i was not set to 1, the program would keep going up and it would miss the fact that 5 is a factor of 175 twice.

Eventually, when i > number, the program knows that it has found all the factors. This is because factors have to be less than the number they are factors of.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

temp isn't used. i=1 resets the checking for factors at 1 once a factor is found

Comment: but value change of i wont influence the for loop?

Comment: @newbie, yes, it will

Answer (score 0):

Here in this code..

```
i = 1
```

resets i as you want the prime factors.. else if it let to increment you will get values like 4 and 6 also.. which would be wrong.

no use of

```
temp = i;
```

Comment: as the value of i is changed,wont (number%i) will always be 0?

Comment: Not really... the for loop will increment it to 2 before going ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Here `temp` variable is not used at all.  You may remove it from pgm.

`i=1` is done, so that checking of remainder `if(number%i==0)` can be started from value 2 again.